# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Framerate cap?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, frame-rate

I'm developing an app for Android using OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm using an LG Optimus 5 phone to test it.

I've created a GLSurfaceView, and I call its renderer's method onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) to show images on screen. I also update the app's logic inside onDrawFrame and sleep to achieve 60FPS.

The code looks like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
//Sleep 16-17ms to achieve 60FPS
//Update
//Render
}
```

One thing I've noticed is I don't need to sleep inside onDrawFrame; apparently my phone's screen refresh rate is 60hz, so Android caps the framerate to 60fps.

So I wonder, does Android always cap the framerate to the refresh rate when using OpenGL ES 2.0?

I thought of obtaining the phone's refresh rate, and if it's 60 don't call the sleep method; if it's higher call it to cap the framerate to 60fps.

What would happen if a phone has a refresh rate lower than 60fps?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android always caps the frame rate at the screen refresh rate. There are no (easy) ways to disable that, it's part of the compositing logic.

For benchmark purposes, where you often want to test how fast you could really render, people often use off-screen rendering. That's the only way to let the GPU render as fast as possible, without a frame rate cap.

Comment: If it always caps the framerate, I'll have to make some changes. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like my approach but overload with what you want to do, then reduce load to achieve 60 FPS.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20graphics%20benchmarks.htm

Example results:

```
 *****************************************************
 T7 Nexus 7 Quad 1300 MHz Cortex-A9, Android 4.1.2
   nVidia ULP GeForce Graphics 12 core, 416 MHz

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 06-Mar-2013 21.51

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+      42.18    43.57    33.38    23.54
  18000+      23.68    23.47    19.91    13.38
  36000+      12.05    11.95    11.00     7.10

      Screen Pixels 1280 Wide 736 High

      Total Elapsed Time  121.0 seconds
```